# Custom WPF user control via repositionable child control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need your help.

I would like to develope a WPF user control via these features:
1. Control should be able to have a content.
2. We should be able to define a position at parent control, where child control should be rendered.

It doesn't seems to be a difficult case, but I insistently can not find any helpfull information. Any information appreciated - I am only begining to learn WPF.

Thanks is advance. :)

[Update]

1. In "Host control" - PartSelectorList:
   1.1. Xaml: < ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Dummy}" Height="50" Visibility="Visible" />
   1.2. Code-behind: DependencyProperty DummyProperty
2. In "Final control":
   2.1. Xaml:
       ...
       < PartSelectorList>
           < PartSelectorList.Dummy>
                   < StackPanel />
           < /PartSelectorList.Dummy>
       < /PartSelectorList>

Comment: No one can/will help you if you don't show how much effort you have already put into it. 1) It can be done by using `ContentControl`. 2) It is parent's (usually Panel) responsibility to decide where the child goes.

Answer (score 1):

why not do something really simple

```
<ContentControl Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="20"> ..content here</ContentControl>
```

Comment: +1 - this is the right answer!  `Canvas` is designed for pixe-positioning of any control.

Comment: I have tried to use ContentControl with property binded to custom user control, but this binded custom user control did not get shown. I have tried different DependencyProperty types (object, UserControl) - no use. :(